# How can I use the algorithm package with the memoir class

Tags: memoir, algorithms

Currently there are no compilation issues.
However, `\listofalgorithms` does not work.

Additionally, my algorithms are missing titles. This is the most important thing for me. How can I get the algorithm titles to appear when I am using algorithms with `memoir`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide a minimal example. This example works fine

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmicx}
\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms
\begin{algorithm}
  asdfasdf
  \caption{test}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```